# Different merged and minified js files in different htmls in one app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, merge, minify

I have an express.js application, it renders pages on server and serves them on different routes - **/home** and **/dashboard** etc., for example, I use several js files, some on all pages, some not:

on home page I use: *jquery.js, underscore.js, somemodule1.js, somemodule2.js*

on dashboard: *jquery.js, underscore.js*, but *somemodule3.js, somemodule4.js*

I need to optimize an app, 'cause I don't want to include files on every html separately..

I need somehow to merge jquery and underscore in *base-merged.js* and other ones to *home-merged.js* and *dashboard-merged.js*. It would be nice to have them minified as well.

Do you now node.js module or maybe grunt plugin for that? The thing I've found - https://npmjs.org/package/merge-js but not sure this will work, I also tried to configure https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin plugin with no luck..

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [uglify.js](https://npmjs.org/package/uglify-js). You can also try [grunt-minified](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-minified) and [express-uglify-middleware](https://npmjs.org/package/express-uglify-middleware).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, by using one single minified js file you can easily achieve it.

You may try to use [grunt-minified](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-minified)

Comment: no, I don't want to use one minified file for all hmtl pages. as you can see I need several merged and minified js files for separate pages..